# Hinting values in a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchbar, google-search, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am saving the values entered in a search bar and I would like to display them when a new search is performed as a hint, in a way Google does in its searches. I would like to have a behavior similar to the UISearchDisplay in tables by overlaying the option under the search allowing the user to either select a value in the list or insert a new one.

Is it possible and is there some tutorial helping to implement it?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Comment: You can create a custom view containing a tableview and the datasource for that table will the values you have saved already. Show this view with some animation when user start typing in search bar. Implement the  '  'searchBarTextDidBeginEditing' delegate  and in that method , filter your stored values array as per search text and reload table in your custom view.

Comment: I was thinking of it, but I hoped there as a ready made code snippet like for UISearchDisplays. I will try, thanks.

Comment: I did it by manually loading the table, yet the cellsForRowAtIndex was not called. So I tried to use a nib file but I have a crash as reported at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937224/when-loading-uivied-from-xib-loadnibnamed-crashes

Comment: I ended up by inserting the view with tableView inside the main controller in the storyboard but cellsForRowAtIndex keeps on not being called notwithstanding numberOfSectionsInTableView returns positive numbers.

Comment: As said I finally inserted the UIView with the UITableView in the main controller and wired it to the UIView subclass adopting UITableSource and UITableDelegate and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up inserting the UIView with the UITableView in the StoryBoard main controller and wiring it to the UIView subclass adopting UITableSource and UITableDelegate and that seems to work fine.