# When loading UIView from Xib, loadNibNamed() crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load a View including a UITableView from a nib by using code:

```
class HintTable:UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
var searchResults = Array<String>()
let delegate:MovableAnnotationDelegate
@IBOutlet var myTableView:UITableView!

init(frame: CGRect, delegate:MovableAnnotationDelegate) {
    self.delegate=delegate
    super.init(frame: frame)
    loadViewFromNib ()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.delegate=InArrivoHDViewController.sharedDetailController()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadViewFromNib ()
}

func loadViewFromNib() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HintTableView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.myTableView.backgroundColor=UIColor(red:0.2890625, green:0.75390625, blue:0.3046875, alpha:0.5)
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor(red:0.2890625, green:0.75390625, blue:0.3046875, alpha:0.5)
    print("myTableView %@", self.myTableView);
    self.myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
}
```

Yet it crashes without any hint whatsoever on command:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HintTableView", owner: self, options: nil)
```

In the Xib I set the class as File's owner instead of getting it in the identity inspector. I am also quite unclear about how to access the tableView, as the IBOutlet seems unwired.

This is a crashlog:

> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x182b3cf48 **exceptionPreprocess + 124 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x197fe7f80 objc_exception_throw + 56 2   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x182b3cc08 -[NSException raise] + 12 3   Foundation
>
>     0x1839b8014 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 268 4
>
>   UIKit                             0x1883e3a4c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate)
>   setValue:forKey:] + 184 5   UIKit                             0x188596794
>   -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 124 6   CoreFoundation                 0x182a669cc -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 232 7   UIKit
>
>     0x18859517c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1748 8   UIKit
>
>     0x188597408 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions)
>   loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 224 9   inArrivoHD
>
>     0x10023218c 0x100074000 + 1827212 10  inArrivoHD
>
>     0x100231bf8 0x100074000 + 1825784 11  inArrivoHD
>
>     0x100231d2c 0x100074000 + 1826092 12  inArrivoHD
>
>     0x10024ec34 0x100074000 + 1944628 13  inArrivoHD
>
>     0x100250678 0x100074000 + 1951352 14  UIKit
>
>     0x1880d0098 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996 15  UIKit
>
>     0x18818f580 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72 16 
>   UIKit                             0x18818f458 -[UINavigationController
>   _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416 17  UIKit                            0x18818e6a0 -[UINavigationController
>   _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144 18  UIKit                            0x18818e244 -[UINavigationController
>   _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868 19  UIKit                            0x18818de6c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
>   20  UIKit                             0x18818ddd4 -[UILayoutContainerView
>   layoutSubviews] + 208 21  UIKit                           0x1880cb7ac
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644 22  QuartzCore                       0x1878cab58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
>   + 148 23  QuartzCore                      0x1878c5764 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292 24  QuartzCore
>
>     0x1878c5624 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
>   + 32 25  QuartzCore                       0x1878c4cc0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252 26  QuartzCore
>     0x1878c4a08 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512 27  QuartzCore
>
>     0x1878be0f8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*,
>   unsigned long, void*) + 80 28  CoreFoundation
>
>     0x182af3bd0
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32 29  CoreFoundation                 0x182af1974 __CFRunLoopDoObservers +
>   372 30  CoreFoundation                    0x182a20cc0
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416 31  UIKit
>     0x18813e1c8 -[UIApplication _run] + 460 32  UIKit
>     0x188138ffc UIApplicationMain + 204 33  inArrivoHD
>     0x1002cc3c0 0x100074000 + 2458560 34  libdyld.dylib
>     0x19882a8b8 start + 4

Comment: Provide exact error that is causing a crash

Comment: I wish I could, in that case I would probably been able to correct myself. Unfortunately it silently crashes on the appDelegate. I was planning to have it crashes on the device to be reported on Quincykit, sometimes more useful than the Xcode debugger, but I have a corrupted table I am now repairing.

Comment: Did you try addding exception breakpoint to catch that ? Also it should drop details in console

Comment: I added the crashlog to my posting. Unfortunately it leaves nothing in the console. As for the exception breakpoint, I just added it and see what comes out.

Comment: Unfortunately the exception breakpoint is totally ignored. The crash keep on appearing in the @ApplicationMain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up inserting the view in the main ViewController of the Storyboard and assigning the delegate and source appropriately to the View.

Comment: From my experience, those kind of crashes come from a misconfigured nib file. Stuff like setting the class name, forgetting to link (or overlinking) outlets, etcetera. Some times it's indeed better to start over, manual nib configuration is kind of tricky ;)